# Speeding up dump process for windows registry using Python

Tags: python-3.x, file, io, registry, winreg

I am trying to take a dump of the HKLM key from the Windows registry, and I want to reduce the time taken to write records to a file. I have used `file.writelines(<iterable>)` and a batch size to limit the number of records that are written to the file, so that the number of writes reduces.

What are some other options that can be used to speed up the dump process? I have used threading as well.